# Requirements for evaluation function in evolutionary algorithms

Tags: genetic-algorithms, function

For a publication I'm looking for references for generic requirements of evaluation/fitness functions in evolutionary (more specifically genetic) algorithms.

I could come up with some requirements myself (efficient implementation, intuitive results, etc.) but I would like some references to existing work, since it should not be new.

Any reference, preferably to papers but if necessary to books, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a (partial) answer to my question. Extensions and replies are welcome!

Could someone especially comment on the 'orthogonal' requirement? The others make sense but I could not find references that talk about orthogonality of metrics in multi-objective evolutionary algorithms.

I currently have the following four requirements:

1. Efficient Implementation. This one is logical and Koza spends a whole appendix (appendix H) on it in his first genetic programming book [1]
2. Intuitive Results. It is clear that best/worst candidates should also have best/worst values in a particular objective. And that the difference in better/worse should be expressed in the value of the metric [2]
3. Clear specification. The way it is calculated (the formula) should be easy to understand for the educated reader, such that the values assigned to candidates can be verified
4. Orthogonal. Different measures should be orthogonal to each other and should not both punish/reward for a particular aspect.

References:

[1] John R. Koza. Genetic Programming: On the Programming of Computers by Means
of Natural Selection. MIT Press, 1992.

[2] Wolfgang Banzhaf, Frank D. Francone, Robert E. Keller, and Peter Nordin. Genetic
programming: an introduction: on the automatic evolution of computer programs and
its applications. Morgan Kaufmann Publishers Inc., San Francisco, CA, USA, 1998